# ng-disabled inside custom directive isn't working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm trying to implement a custom directive that forces the user to hold a button instead of just clicking it, preventing numerous mistakes. A material design slider is present under the button to show how long the user has to click on the button.

But sometimes, there has to be moments where the button must not be clickable, for example if there is a form with incorrect values.
I tried to set the ng-disabled attribute but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong ?

Js :

```
negoceExpedApp.directive('rkMouseHold', function ($interval, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '=buttonText',
            callback: '&callback',
            isDisabled: '&isDisabled'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: "<div style='width:fit-content'>" +
            "<md-button ng-disabled='{{disabled}}' class='md-accent md-raised md-hue-400'>{{ text }} - {{ disabled }}</md-button><br>" +
            "<md-progress-linear ng-show='c!=0' class='md-accent md-hue-400' md-mode='determinate' value='{{c/10}}'></md-progress-linear>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(scope.isDisabled,(newVal)=>{
                console.log("%c newVal","color:orange",newVal);
                if(newVal==true){
                    scope.disabled = "true";
                } else {
                    scope.disabled = 'false';
                }
            })
            scope.c = 0;
            scope.loop = null;
            element.on('mousedown', () => {
                scope.loop = $interval(function () {
                    $timeout(() => {
                        scope.c += 100
                    }, 0);
                }, 100);
            });

            element.on('mouseup', () => {
                $interval.cancel(scope.loop);
                if (scope.c > 1000) {
                    scope.callback();
                }
                scope.c = 0;
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Html :

```
<rk-mouse-hold callback="ctrl.saveForm()"
               is-disabled="expedForm.$invalid"
               button-text="'HOLD TO SAVE'">
</rk-mouse-hold>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngDisabled` is just a wrap-up for regular `disabled` directive, that supports interpolation. Now here how you setting disabled value

```
   if(newVal==true){
        scope.disabled = "true";
    } else {
        scope.disabled = 'false';
    }
```

can be simplified to

```
  scope.disabled = !!newVal;
```

And in the template

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <md-button ng-disabled='{{disabled}}' class='md-accent md-raised md-hue-400'>
>     {{ text }} - {{ disabled }}
> </md-button><br>"
> ```

use `ng-disabled='disabled'` instead of `ng-disabled='{{disabled}}'`

In this case you are passing exact boolean value, while what you doing - each time you are passing string value, which is considered as true.

After all, in your scope you defined your custom disabled like so

```
isDisabled: '&isDisabled'
```

`&` is used for evaluated expressions or callback, if you want to pass a variable. Checkout this [great article](https://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/) as for correct bindings, and replace your code to

```
isDisabled: '@'
```

Comment: Everything works now except if I put @ in the binding. It works with '&isDisabled'